# Expo v33 Managed Application - Facebook and Google login not working on deployed iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, expo, google-signin

It works on Android as well as on the Simulator and Expo Client but doesn't work when we publish the App on the App Store or manually add `.ipa` on the iPad.

Have tried most of the solutions

https://blog.expo.io/react-native-google-sign-in-with-expo-d1707579a7ce
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/

Getting the following error for Facebook:

```
Tried t operform Facebook login iwth behavior '(null)'
, but no Facebook app id was provided. 
Specify app id in Info.plist or switch to 'web' behavior
```

Google failing as well and not able to get any error for Google.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2989

Comment: Checked it @Oleg, but no solutions/recommendations are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since this is a very fresh incident, I inform that this response is not a definitive answer, but rather an educated guess.

I am also facing this issue, and in my case it is working fine on simulator using expo app version 2.13.x but happening while running the expo app (version 2.14.1.107621) on physical iphone.

I haven't tested on android (neither simulator nor real device), but most people say it is happening on iOS only.

I did some research and found that according to [expo SDK 36 blog post](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-36-is-now-available-b91897b437fe), the facebook module now has to be initialized with `initializeAsync()` BEFORE calling `logInWithReadPermissionsAsync()`. Of course that this should be applicable only to apps using version 36 of expo SDK, but maybe the latest expo-cli (3.11.1) and expo-app (2.14.x) for iOS have issues that prevent them from realizing the legacy behaviour on facebook module of previous SDKs (like mine, version 33), thus producing the error.

Meanwhile, let us see the new replies on this thread of expo forums: https://forums.expo.io/t/facebook-login-promise-rejection-on-ios/30969

Comment: Great Igor, I haven't touched this in a while, but I will try your suggestion soon.